# How to show that a quadratic over linear function is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The problem occurs in the [Convex Optimization II lecture by Stephen Boyd](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/subgrad_method_notes.pdf). There we want to choose $\alpha_i$'s to minimize $$\frac{R^2+G^2 \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i^2}{2\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i}$$

where $\alpha_i>0,R>0,G>0$. The professor argued this in the [video 20:00](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B51GgGCHBRk) with the statement that a quadratic over a positive linear function is convex. How to show that it is true? Also, could somebody give a proof for the general case where the function is of the form:$$\frac{x^T Ax+b^Tx+c}{d^Tx+e}$$
with $\textbf{Dom}(x)=\{x:d^Tx+e>0\}$ and $A$ positive semi-definite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function of many variables is convex iff every one-dimensional slice of it is also convex, so it's enough to consider the 1-variable case. So suppose $$f(x)=\frac{\frac12ax^2+bx+c}{dx+e};$$

then a bit of calculation yields

$$(dx+e)^3f''(x)=ae^2-2bde+2cd^2$$

so we want the RHS of that (a constant, which is a promising start) to be positive. Well, it's a quadratic function of $e$ whose discriminant is $(bd)^2-(a)(2cd^2)=(b^2-2ac)d^2$.

If the numerator of $f$ is an *everywhere-positive* quadratic (which I think the lecturer intended, though he didn't say it, and is certainly true of his particular function) then $b^2-ac<0$ and also $a>0$ (to make the numerator positive for large $x$) and $c>0$ (to make the numerator positive for $x=0$), and therefore the discriminant in the previous paragraph is also $<0$ (unless $d=0$, but in that case our function is convex for easier reasons), and therefore $ae^2-2bde+2cd^2$ has the same sign for all $e$ and in particular the same sign as $2cd^2$, i.e., the same sign as $c$. And since, again, we are assuming that our numerator is positive everywhere, $c>0$ and we're done.

(You can maybe save some of that "bit of calculation", which I got wrong at least twice, as follows: consider the function $g(x,y)=\frac{ax^2+b}y$. The second derivatives of this are pretty painless to compute and it's then easy to see that $g$ is convex where $y>0$. And now we can use the fact that an affine-then-convex composition is itself convex.)

Comment: $f''(x)$ is correct, but the discriminant is not.

Comment: Do you mean we have a different convention for what the discriminant is (I prefer to write my quadratics as $ax^2+2bx+c=0$ and say that the discriminant is $b^2-ac$) or that I have done something actually wrong in my calculation? I make a lot of mistakes but I'm not seeing one right now.

Comment: I have only ever seen $ax^2+bx+c=0$ with discriminant $b^2-4ac$. Under your alternative convention, the discriminant would instead be $(-bd)^2-a(2cd^2)$, so you are missing a $2$.

Comment: Oh, duh, I am indeed missing a factor of 2. Thanks.

Comment: Fortunately the argument was readily fixable. Should be OK now. Thanks once again.

Comment: Strangely I've never heard of the reduction to the 1-variable case even though it sounds way simpler than the Hessian-criterion. Could you point me to a precise definition of it?

Comment: Well, the _definition_ of a convex function is one for which the set of points above its graph is convex, or equivalently one for which $f((1-t)a+tb)\geq (1-t)f(a)+tf(b)$, and for any $a,b$ that condition only involves points lying in a single plane.

Comment: @ Gareth McCaughan Thank you very much for your devotion, but I want to mention that for a multivariate function, one way to prove its convexity is by verifying its Hessian is positive semi-definite. Your answer have proved that the diagonal elements of the Hessian are all nonnegative, but it is not enough for the function to be convex. For instance, $f(x,y)=-x y$ is a counterexample. By the way, I recommend you a powerful tool for computing mathematical stuff, Mathematica, which can save you huge amounts of time. Really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: The function $f(x,y)=-xy$ does not have the property that every one-dimensional slice is convex. For instance, if we slice along $y=x$ then the 1-dimensional function that results is $f(x)=-x^2$ which is not convex. (Did you perhaps think I meant "one-dimensional slice _parallel to a coordinate axis_"? I didn't.)

Comment: To be more precise about what I did mean: suppose we have a function $f:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $V$ is any vector space.  $f$ is convex iff every restriction $f|_A:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is convex, where $A$ is a one-dimensional affine subspace of $V$.

Comment: (I am familiar with Mathematica.)

Comment: @ Gareth McCaughan I got what you mean by one-dimensional slice. Your answer is perfect. I overlooked a fact that we can use parametric form of a line to reduce $f$ to a univariate function.